# I'm going to write AVI file from webcam using opencv in MFC project, but it isn't written

Tags: c++, opencv, mfc

I'm modifying a program with webcam monitoring function. I have to add a function that write *.avi file from webcam. I added some member variables and codes in CMainForm class.

Below code is added member variables;

```
CvVideoWriter* m_Writer;
IplImage* m_Image;
CvCapture* m_Capture;
bool m_bAviWriting;    // Checks whether avi file is being written
```

And I modified a function implements when Start button is clicked. I replaced local variables to new member variables.

```
...
m_Capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(m_nCameraNumber);
    if (m_Capture == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    m_Image = 0;

    m_Image = cvQueryFrame(m_Capture);
    m_Image = cvQueryFrame(m_Capture);
    m_Image = cvQueryFrame(m_Capture);

    // Create file
    if (!m_bAviWriting) {
        m_Capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(m_nCameraNumber);
        m_Image = cvQueryFrame(m_Capture);
        CvSize size = cvSize((int)cvGetCaptureProperty(m_Capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
            (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(m_Capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
        m_Writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("writehere.avi", CV_FOURCC('D', 'V', 'I', 'X'), 30.0, size);

        m_bAviWriting = true;
```

And added a function that executes whenever CxxxView::OnDraw() excutes.

```
void CMainFrame::WriteAvi()
{
    m_ImgForFile = cvQueryFrame(m_CaptureForFile);
    if (!m_ImgForFile) return;
    if (m_Writer == NULL) {
        m_Writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("writehere.avi", CV_FOURCC('D', 'V', 'I', 'X'), 30.0, cvGetSize(m_ImgForFile), 1);
    }
    cvShowImage("rspWindow", m_ImgForFile);
    cvWriteFrame(m_Writer, m_ImgForFile);
}
```

Finally, modified a function executes when Stop button is clicked.

```
if (m_bAviWriting) {
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&m_Writer);
    cvReleaseCapture(&m_Capture);
    m_bAviWriting = false;
}
```

When this program run, blank file "writehere.avi" is created, but contents are not written. During debbuging, I found that m_Writer instance has null value all time, but I can't discover why.

Comment: `DVIX` is not a well-known FOURCC code. Did you mean to use `DIVX` instead?

Comment: Thank you for comment. It can be my mistake. I will try again.